# Fixed Footer Solution for older browsers

Tags: html, css

I'm in the process of building a mobile website that is targeted towards developing countries, which means that most of the mobile phones will be older feature phones using pretty basic browsers with limited css support and typically no javascript.

One of things I'm trying to achieve is a fixed footer solution that would be supported on older browsers.

Via this site I found a link to this solution [Ryan Fait Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) which seemed good in theory but which I cannot get to work.

Here is my jsfiddle which is my understanding of how the code should be implemented. Would appreciate it if you could have a look and let me know what (if anything) I'm doing wrong

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w9mFr/)

Here is my partial code;

**HTML Code**

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<p>Text</p>
<div class="push"></div>
<div class="footer">This is a test</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
* {margin: 0;} 
html, body {height: 100%;}
.wrapper {min-height: 100%;height: auto !important;height: 100%;margin: 0 auto -155px;}
.footer, .push {height: 155px;}
```

Comment: `Solution for older browsers`? Which browsers? How old are they? What's wrong to stick with `position: fixed`?

Comment: BTW: Please do not use `!important` in CSS! http://james.padolsey.com/usability/dont-use-important/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not closed the wrapper DIV.  Close this before the footer.  See the new fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/sF4EB/3/

Be aware, this won't stick the footer to the bottom of the window at all times (you need to use `position: fixed` for that), just at the bottom of the window if the page isn't tall enough to push it there, otherwise it will remain at the bottom of the content.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and clarification. Unfortunately, position: fixed is not an option for me due to lack of support on older browsers.